# In a Powershell advanced function, in what block should I open an external file?

Tags: powershell, parameters, pipeline

I am writing an advanced function called Get-Store, where it will be used within other scripts (on the pipeline) or by users at the prompt (regular old parameters). The user will be entering a 4-character alphanumeric code representing one or more stores. Alternatively, the store code(s) will be piped to the function. I have omitted the code for what the function does, but briefly, it opens an Excel file, looks up the store code for parameter validation, and then outputs a StoreObject with all that store's information in it.

Now, so far, I've been opening the Excel file in the Begin block, and that works fine when piping store codes to it, like `"M101","M102","M103" | Get-Store`. However, with `Get-Store "M101","M102","M103"`, it'll complain that the Excel file isn't open.

I think I've landed on what the problem might be. I can illustrate what's going on:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "Default")]

param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "Default")]
    [SupportsWildcards()]
    [ValidateScript({
        Write-Host "Inside Validate..."
        $true
    })]
    [string[]]
    $StoreCode
)

Begin {

    # Open excel file here
    Write-Host "Inside Begin block..."    
}


Process {

    Write-Host "Inside Process block..."
    $StoreCode | Write-Host
}


End {

    # Close Excel file here
    Write-Host "Inside End block..."
}
```

When I run this on the pipeline (e.g., `PS> "M101","M102","M103" | Get-Store`), I get:

```
Inside Begin block...
Inside Validate...
Inside Process block...
M101
Inside Validate...
Inside Process block...
M102
Inside Validate...
Inside Process block...
M103
Inside End block...
```

When I run it with regular parameters (e.g., `Get-Store.ps1 "M101","M102","M103"`), I get:

```
Inside Validate...
Inside Validate...
Inside Validate...
Inside Begin block...
Inside Process block...
M101
M102
M103
Inside End block...
```

The first would show that I should open my Excel file in the Begin block. The second would show I should open my Excel file (which is used for both validation and for building my StoreObject) during parameter validation. It seems to me that putting it in the validation scriptblock would necessitate code that would keep it from opening a COM instance for every store code being validated (which would be a disaster if the user selected the -All switch).

But where should I open my Excel file so it's open and available whether it's in the Validate block or the Begin/Process blocks?

Comment: you definitely do not want to open your excel in the `ValidateScript` block. All validation should be done in the `process` block for a pipeline function

Comment: How big is the Excel file?

Comment: 20 sheets, each 24 columns and 50-60 rows

Comment: Hmm, I seem to have not explained myself well enough. Thank you both for your answers. But the point of my code was to show the order of operations. For use in the pipeline, the Begin block executes first and parameter validation is second. For parameter input, Parameter validation runs first and the Begin block executes second. So I need to somehow open Excel to get the valid Store code values before the Begin block. But that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you should follow but **is restricted to PowerShell 7.3+** is the following, you definitely do not want to open your file in the `ValidateScript` block and you should do any needed validation in the `process` block of your function, in addition the Excel file should be opened in the `process` block of any pipeline compatible function.

**This pattern requires [`clean` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.3#clean), but why?**

Because it is ensured that this block will run even for a [`PipelineStoppedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) thus you can ensure that the opened handle can be disposed correctly.

For versions below **PowerShell 7.3**, the best you can do is depose in the `end` block, but you should be very aware that this does not ensure the file handle will be disposed, i.e.: if pressing <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> in the middle of your function.

```bash
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Default')]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'Default')]
    [SupportsWildcards()]
    [string[]]
    $StoreCode
)

begin {
    Write-Host 'Inside Begin block...'
    $isFirstObject = $true
}
process {
    # this is the first object coming from pipeline
    if($isFirstObject) {
        # open excel here
        $excel = ....
        # and set this boolean to `$false` so we enter this condition only once
        $isFirstObject = $false
    }

    Write-Host 'Inside Process block...'
    $StoreCode
}
clean {
    Write-Host 'Inside End block...'
    # here we validate if `$excel` was opened
    # then, dispose excel here
}
```

As for why it's important to open your file in the `process` block, suppose the previous cmdlet in the pipeline is not producing any output ([AutomationNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.3#empty-null)), then your `begin` and `end` block would run anyways and you would be opening your file for no particular reason which is why the optimal approach is to do this in the `process` block.